# Translating RCL assembly into C/C++

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, inline-assembly

I'm trying to manually translate some assembly into C/C++ in order to migrate a code-base to x64 bit as Visual Studio does not allow `__asm` code to compile in x64 bit.

I've translated some parts, however I am stuck on the following (it's an extract from the full function but should be self-contained):

```
void Foo()
{
    char cTemp = ...;
    int iVal = ...;

    __asm
    {
        mov ebx, iVal

        mov dl, cTemp
        mov al, dl

        MOV CL, 3

        CLC

        MOV AX, BX
        ROR AH, CL
        XOR DL, AH
        SAR DL, 1
        RCL BX, 1
        RCL DL, 1
    }
}
```

The parts I'm struggling with are:

```
RCL BX, 1
RCL DL, 1
```

From what I understand this is the equivalent of the following:

```
short v = ...;
v = (v << 1) + (CLEAR_FLAG ? 1 : 0)
```

Which from my understanding means if the value of `(v << 1)` overflows then add 1, otherwise add 0 (I may be mis-understanding though, so please correct me if so).

What I'm struggling to do is detect the overflow in C/C++ when carrying the shift operation. I've looked around and the only thing I can find is detecting addition/subtraction overflow before it happens, but nothing with regards to bit shifting.

Is it possible at all to translate such assembly to C/C++?

Comment: Don't overlook the preceeding instruction `SAR DL, 1` which sets up the carry for the next `RCL`.

Comment: In the [non-official] ISA pages for `RCL` et. al., they have sample C code to explain the instructions: https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_273.html Also, use `unsigned short` instead of `short`

Comment: The function as shown doesn't *do* anything with the results.

Comment: What do you do with `BX` and `DL` when you are done? What is the purpose of ` mov al, dl` ? You overwrite `al` shortly thereafter with `MOV AX, BX`.

Comment: This code has no effect since it doesn't `mov` a result to a named C variable that can be accessed outside the asm block.  And it's `void` so the value left in EAX isn't a return value.  Anyway, `rcl bx,1` is like `adc bx,bx`, shifting a bit from CF (*carry* flag) into the bottom of BX, like you're showing.  The bit shifted out goes into CF, so `rcl dl,1` puts the bit shifted out into the bottom of DL.

Comment: Thanks all for the info. I've purposely made the function as simple as possible as I mainly wanted to understand how to translate the RCL part, so didn't think the rest of the function was needed.

So that I understand fully, what is exactly meant by `SAR DL, 1` setting the carry flag for the next RCL? Does that mean if `SAR DL, 1` overflow, the carry flag is set for the next instruction?

Comment: No, read the instruction-set manual: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sal:sar:shl:shr for shifts, and  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rcl:rcr:rol:ror.   CF = the bit shifted out.  So `DL & 1` for the DL value *before* the shift.  FYI, this is standard behaviour for shifts across most ISAs that have a carry flag.

Comment: Quite often it helps to figure out at a high level what the asm is accomplishing overall, then reimplement that in C, which is why we're asking what happens later.  Rather than transliterating each operation one by one.  If you need to do that as a first step, though, hopefully an optimizing compiler can sort out the mess.  Hopefully the asm doesn't depend on writing partial registers and then reading the full register, or you'd have to implement that part in C, merging partial-register writes (to DL) back into `uint32_t EDX`, or making it a union.

Comment: @PeterCordes - Please see the edit for the full function. I believe the function is attempting to do some string transformation, but hard to tell as I'm not too familiar with assembly.

In terms of translating the SAR and RCL bits, if I understood I need to do >> bit shift for the SAR instruction, however not very sure on how to query the carry flag after that so that I can use it for the following RCL equivalent in C/C++. Hope that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't written the function so whatever sins it has are not mine (thankfully) :)

Comment: Does the function name shed any light on the purpose?  Is it some kind of "decryption" of data obfuscated data, or is it just really inefficient and/or obfuscated code?  The final DL / EDX value isn't used, so the final `rcl dl, 1` is useless.  Also, `mov al, dl` is useless because nothing reads it or AL before `MOV AX,BX`.  `clc` is useless because `ror` writes CF before anything has read that zeroed CF.  The loop at the end appears separate, and might be wrapping the `al` value into some range like  `<= (unsigned)'z'` or `>= (unsigned)'A'`.  Looks pretty inefficient and messy.

Comment: Looking at some sample inputs and outputs (before the branchy part, and from the whole asm statement) might help figure out what it's doing, like giving a hint about what to look for in the asm about how it gets from point A to B.

Comment: @PeterCordes - Function name doesn't give much away I'm afraid, but it does look to be some obfuscation technique. I agree it's messy hence why I'd really like to convert it to C/C++ at least (and also to be able to use 64 bit with Visual Studio).

Is it translatable or am I stuck with it? I can sort of translate the last bits that are comparing to ASCII values, but it's the SAR and RCL bits I'm quite struggling with.

Comment: Of course it's translatable; C is Turing-complete.  It just doesn't look like anything obvious or straightforward, and is more than I could keep track of in my head while writing comments.  So it would need more work and testing to be sure it's correct.  It looks like it's updating `iInput` across iterations, so after 8 `RCL BX, 1` there will be some non-zero bits in the top half of its low 16 bits and the XORing will start to do something.  So when processing the 3rd character.

Comment: Please post answers as answers, not edits to the question.  Unless you're asking whether that's correct, in which case your `LOWORD(x)` macro has strict-aliasing UB.  Your byte macros are safe assuming `uint8_t` is `unsigned char`, but you're just making life difficult for the compiler for no reason; like I said, this code doesn't read wider registers after writing a full register, except for `mov iInput, ebx`.  But just use `uint16_t iInput` instead; its high 16 bits are never touched.

Comment: MSVC does define the behaviour of that pointer-casting, but there's just no need to use that non-portable code.  You're likely going to tempt some compilers into storing and reloading with disastrous performance.  (Store-forwarding stalls from a narrow store and reloading a wider value.)

Comment: Also, `_EBX` is a reserved name, since it starts with an underscore and upper-case letter.  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20230109-00/?p=107685  .  IDK why people love to use underscore names when they could just use `uint16_t bx` and stuff like `uint8_t c = bx; // truncate to 8 bit`

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes, yes I was wanting to confirm if the code is correct first, especially that it will be used in both 32 and 64 bit exe. Are you suggesting I just use _EBX directly rather than setting or getting LOWORD?

Yeah not going to use underscores in the final code, this came from the disassembler :)

Comment: I'm saying you should use `uint16_t bx` and `uint16_t iInput;`.  The high 16 bits of both are always zero; look at the initializer for `iInput` and the fact that nothing in the asm ever writes EBX except by writing the low 16 bits, or loading from `iInput`.  Nothing can ever shift a bit into the high half or otherwise set one there.  And `BYTE1` is just `bx >> 8` for `uint16_t bx`.

Comment: Ah I see didn't spot that nothing wrote the EBX. Makes sense. Thanks a lot for your input, appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`RCL`](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Assembly/A77_0420_rotate_with_carry.htm) is a "rotate left with carry" operation. So you need to take into account the previous instruction, `SAR`, that sets the carry flag (CF).

Note that [`SAR`](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Flags/F77_0160_sar_instruction.htm) is a signed right shift, so will need a signed operand. It important to use proper data types that match the instruction precisely in bitness and signedness.

A 1-to-1 translation could look something like this

```cpp
int8_t dl = /* ... */;
uint16_t bx = /* ... */;

//           SAR DL,1
int8_t carry_1 = dl & 1;
dl >>= 1;

//           RCL BX,1
uint16_t carry_2 = bx >> 15;
bx = (bx << 1) | carry_1;

//           RCL DL,1
dl = (dl << 1) | carry_2;
```

There is probably a way to simplify these further. There are tools that can do that, they provide a somewhat readable C++ equivalent for a decompiled function.

Comment: Also any example of tools that may help please?

Comment: We don't do [softwarerecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) here at SO. But, as an exception, I've used hex-rays at work before. It's not free though.

Comment: *There is probably a way to simplify these further.* - Indeed, we never actually need to shift `dl` since `sar` and `rcl` cancel out for the high 7 bits, just bit-blend to replace the low bit.  e.g. `dl = (dl & 0xfe) | (bx>>15)`.  (It also doesn't matter that it was an arithmetic (signed) right shift instead of logical (unsigned), since the bit shifted in gets shifted back out, and critically it's not read later; the next usage for FLAGS is write-only, the `sar` in the next block.)  Assuming the compiler wouldn't actually have used `shr` / `adc ebx,ebx` (or a slower RCL), this may be faster.

Comment: @Kakalokia: actually even with Rusty's C source, gcc and clang both do just mask and OR a new low bit from `bx >> 15`, not shifting `dl` right then left.  https://godbolt.org/z/z6oxq91zd  (Looking at it in a stand-alone function taking args means some overhead of zero-extending the incoming args when the calling convention doesn't guarantee they're free of high garbage, or sign-extending the return value.)  GCC and clang use AArch64 `bfi` (bitfield insert) for this when compiling for that ISA.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/aG1TPP5GY includes the rotate between two iterations of this.  Compilers for x86-64 don't spot a lot of optimizations, they still actually do an 8-bit ROR.  (By an immediate `3` instead of putting a count in `cl` for no reason.)  But for AArch64, they're not actually rotating.  Oh right, of course, because AArch64 only has 32 and 64-bit rotates, so they have to use `ubfx` (unsigned bitfield extract) and `orr` with a shifted input operand to get a rotate done in 2 instructions.  (@Kakalokia)

Comment: Thanks both. I've updated the question with the final translation that I managed to get. It's very ugly and inefficient but at least it's not assembler. I'll need to tidy it up but at least for now it outputs the same result as the assembler version. I think I got all the types and sign/bitness correct, along with the usage of LOWORD @PeterCordes